# correct use of similar /to/with/like/

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it correct to say `similar with` or `similar to` or `similar like`? Consider the following sentences

> He has similar behavior with his friends (He has a behavior similar with his friend)
>
> He has similar behavior to his friends   (He has a behavior similar to his friend)
>
> He has similar behavior like his friend

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We always say `similar to`. In this definition of [similar](http://thefreedictionary.com/similar), it is expressly written that "As should not be used after similar".

> Wilson held a similar position *to* Jones (not a similar position *as* Jones);

Comment: similar to - familiar with, always confuse ...

Answer (score 4):

For me:
He has similar behavior with his friends = "similar" here is just an adjective and is not connected with the word "with". Just because I say "he has similar behaviour when he is with me", it doesn't mean there is a structure "similar when"

"He has similar behavior to his friends = "similar to" is correct (his behaviour and his friends' behaviour are similar)

He has similar behavior like his friend = I wouldn't use this as "similar" and "like" have the same kind of meaning here, it's  repetition. ("He has similar behaviour to his friends" OR "his behaviour is like his friends' behaviour).

The structure is **SIMILAR TO**
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The deciding factor is whether the figure of speech is convergent or divergent.  Therefore, we have **similar to** and **different from**.